# dropdown of top navbar hides behind second navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 navbars on my site. Recently I had to change the top navbar to `static` insted of `fixed` since `fixed` messed up the website on my mobile.

However that brough another problem, now my dropdown from the first navbar hides behind the second. How can I fix this? I really want this dropdown on my site.

My code (kind of, had to remove som asp-tags): http://www.bootply.com/MqSaaOTeZr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

comment z-index in bootstrap.min.css

```
.navbar-static-top {
    /* z-index: 1000; */
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
}
```